# How to use Keycloak for authentication with custom sign in page of angular?

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am using Keycloak's user federation with LDAP for authentication in my application. The frontend is built with Angular, and I would like to use a custom sign-in page in Angular instead of the default login page provided by Keycloak.

I am able to fetch the tokens by making a POST request to the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/realms/ruconsole/protocol/openid-connect/token`

This endpoint provides the access_token, but it doesn't store the necessary cookies that would typically be set if we used Keycloak's default login page.

I am uncertain about the workflow I need to follow to use Keycloak with my custom login page and how to ensure the necessary session management and token handling are performed correctly.

Could someone provide guidance on how to integrate Keycloak with a custom login page in Angular and ensure proper session management and token handling?

Comment: Instead of trying to move login page to our codebase, we styled Keykloak's login page. Same when we worked with MSAL.